# Convert powerpoint slides to word document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-powerpoint

Is there any tool to convert powerpoint slides to word document. I have lectures that has many slides to be printed out as word so that it could save space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For PowerPoint 2007:

- Open your PowerPoint presentation.
- Click on the `Office button > Publish > Create Handouts in Microsoft Word`.

[image]

For PowerPoint 2003:

- Open your PowerPoint presentation.
- Choose `File > Send to > Microsoft Office Word`.

[image]

**5 Options for Converting PowerPoint to Word Documents**

Converting PowerPoint presentations to Word documents can be done in five different ways:

1. Notes next to slides
2. Blank lines next to slides
3. Notes below slides
4. Blank lines below slides
5. Outline only

[image]

One really great feature that PowerPoint offers when it converts your presentation to a Word document is the choice of `Paste` or `Paste Link`. Here is the difference:

- **Paste:** Choosing Paste will simply create the handout in the style you have chosen.
- **Paste Link:** Choosing Paste Link will create a handout in the style you choose as well. However, if the PowerPoint presentation is later edited, the changes will also be reflected in the Word document the next time it is opened. This is not the case when you choose the Paste command.